# With stochastic variable $X$ with density $2xe^{-x^2}$ and $Y=X^2$. Calculate $EY^n$

Tags: measure-theory

I have some homework that says:

Let X be a real-valued stochastic variable with with density $f(x)=2xe^{-x^2}$ wrt Lebesgue measure for x>0. Let the distribution $Y=X^2$. Calculate $EY^n$

I calculated the distribution as $$Y=X^2 =  y \cdot e^{-y} $$

Then my approach is:
Let $Y=X^2$ and the transformation $t(y)=Y^n$

Using a theorem I get:
$$E \, t(x)=\int t \cdot f \, d\mu = EY^n= \int y^n \cdot y \cdot e^{-y} \, dm(y)$$
$$= \int y^{n+1}  \cdot e^{-y} \, dm(y)$$

But this does not seem to be finite?

Comment: $X$ is not equal to $2x e^{-x^2}$, which seems implied from what you wrote. If you are okay with integrating against the distribution  of $Y$ with $t(y)=y^{n}$, why not simply integrate against the distribution of $X$ with the function $t(x)=x^{2n}$?

Comment: The PDF takes value $0$ for negative $x$ (not mentioned in your question).Can you solve integral $\mathbb{E}Y^{n}=\int_{0}^{\infty}2x^{2n+1}e^{-x^{2}}dx$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta No I didn't, as described, I wrote the text as in the textbook

Comment: @EpsilonDelta so remove the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $EY^{n}=EX^{2n}=\int_0^{\infty} 2x^{2n+1} e^{-x^{2}}dx$. Put $y=x^{2}$ and the integral becomes $\int_0^{\infty} y^{n} e^{-y}dy$.  I will leave it to you to evaluate this integral.

Comment: What happened to the constant 2 and the "+1" in $x^{2n+1}$?

Comment: @Daniel If $y=x^{2}$ then $dy=2xdx$. So $2x$ gets absorbed in $dy$.